# Override constructor with an class decorator?

Tags: javascript, class, decorator, ecmascript-next

How can I override a constructor with an ES7 class decorator?

For example, I'd like to have something like:

```
@injectAttributes({ foo: 42 })
class Bar {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}
```

Where the `injectAttributes` decorator will inject attributes into new instances before they are created:

```
> bar = new Bar();
42
> bar.foo
42
```

The obvious solution – using a different constructor:

```
 function overrideConstructor(cls, attrs) {
   Object.assign(this, attrs);
   cls.call(this);
 }
```

Does not work because the object created will be an instance of the new constructor, not the original type:

```
 > bar = new overrideConstructor(Bar, {foo: 42})
 42
 > bar
 [overrideConstructor {}]
 > bar instanceof Bar
 false
```

Comment: There are no decorators in ES7.

Comment: _"Does not work because the object created will be an instance of the new constructor, not the original type"_ There is no "original type". `Bar` is the result of the decoration. Or rather would be, because there are no decorators in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

The BabelJS REPL doesn't support decorators so I am using the function (and manually wrapping) but the concept is the same.

[Here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=function%20injectAttributes(cls%2C%20attrs)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20injected%20%3D%20function(...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20attrs)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20cls.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20injected.prototype%20%3D%20cls.prototype%3B%0A%20%20return%20injected%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20BareBar%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.foo)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20Bar%20%3D%20injectAttributes(BareBar%2C%20%7B%20foo%3A%205%20%7D)%0A%0Aconst%20thing%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0Aconsole.log(thing%20instanceof%20Bar)%3B%0A) is the code working, and the copy/paste below:

```js
function injectAttributes(cls, attrs) {
  const injected = function(...args) {
    Object.assign(this, attrs);
    return cls.apply(this, args);
  }
  injected.prototype = cls.prototype;
  return injected;
}


class BareBar {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}
const Bar = injectAttributes(new BareBar, { foo: 5 })

const thing = new Bar();
console.log(thing instanceof Bar);
```

This prints:

```js
5
true
```

The decorator creates a new constructor, where attributes are injected, and then copies over the original prototype so that `instanceof` works.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor BareBar cannot be invoked without 'new'`