# Wrapping a constructor with javascript method decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, decorator, ecmascript-next

Referenced: 
[Override constructor with an class decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796074/override-constructor-with-an-class-decorator)
http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-ii

I'd like to wrap a classes constructor with a custom one when applying a method decorator (ie in the same way you could do with a class decorator). I require this as I have another component that will call into the class, and will execute the method that was decorated. Its not hard to have the component execute the method that was decorated, however because the decorator is run before the class is instantiated the decorated method will not be associated with a class instance and therefore will not have access to any of the classes state (ie this == undefined). So I want to be able to provide the method reference to the component during class instantiation (ie constructor) so that it is bound to the current instance.

So I'd like to do this (typescript):

```
class Foo {
  constructor(private value) { }

  @execute
  bar() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Which would have the same affect as doing this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(private value) {
    StaticComponent.AddReference(this.bar().bind(this));
}

  bar() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

If my other component has a reference to bar() it should be able to execute it with bar having full access to its instance.

I've tried to override the prototype of the target etc in a similar way you might do so for a class decorator, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't follow. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to `bind` the `bar()` to the instance?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear - I've rewrote the question to make it clearer. Please let me know if its still not clear what I'm after - thanks. Though to you question yes.

Comment: Why can't you do it the other way around and let `AddReference` bind whatever function is passed to it?

Comment: At the point that I'm passing the reference of bar() in AddReference there is no reference to this (ie its undefined as an instance hasn't been created yet). So its not possible to have AddReference do the binding.

Comment: If you have no instance, you can not bind. I am sorry, but I have no clue what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you find your pattern here: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: I'm currently solving my issue with two decorators. The method decorator adds the details of the method to a property that's added to the prototype ie __hanlders. The second decorator is a class decorator which wraps the constructor and reads this data and adds the method references while binding to the current instance. You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/dotnetprofessional/ABusJS/blob/master/app/Decorators.ts

Comment: @dnp how did you solve this? The link is dead!

Comment: @select sorry I refactored that code to use Lerna which made me move everything. Here's the link again: https://github.com/dotnetprofessional/ABusJS/tree/master/packages/abus/app/Decorators. In short I had to register what I wanted with the handler decorator (method) and then use the iHandleMessages (class decorator) to make use of that info, that's now on the prototype and register with my static class. Hope this helps!